# Create log scale in highstock

Tags: highcharts

how to create a log scale in highstock like a log scale in this highchart http://www.highcharts.com/demo/line-log-axis  ?

if i use a setting like this type: 'logarithmic',minorTickInterval: 0.1 
in highstock remained does not succeed

Answer (score 3):

Please take look at example with Highstock,

http://jsfiddle.net/7DDz8/

```
 yAxis: {
            type: 'logarithmic',
            minorTickInterval: 0.1
        },
```